# How to do load balancing works on app server level in SharePoint on-premise 3 tier architecture

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, load-balancing, windows-server-2008-r2, 3-tier

We are configuring SharePoint 2013 3 tier architecture. We are configuring services on servers. Now the requirement is:

1) All the services should be hosted on both the app servers, can we do this?

2) Both app server should balance there load

3) If one app server down then other app server should take care and system should not down

4) There is a feature NLB in Windows servers, will it work for app servers for the above cases?

Its urgent. Please help with the best approach.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Only the SharePoint foundation web  application services must be activated on the WFEs. The other services such as managed metadata services, search service, performance point services are activated/enabled on the APP SERVERS. Let us know the number of users   who are accessing the farm.Also concurrency  as well. if the number of users is  more than 1000  it must be a medium farm with mini.  2 WFEs and 2 SQL Server boxes and 2 APP Servers. if users are less than 1000 , then its a small farm topology.

Comment: We checked same for Central admin. Site is hosted on App1 and App2 but when we are clicking on SharePoint Central Admin link in Start menu then it is browsing the App1 CA only. If App1 is down then App2 should be browsable. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, with the exception of the User Profile Synchronization Service, if you choose to use it. It may only run on one server in the farm per User Profile Service Application (likely you'll only have one).

2) SharePoint has an internal round-robin load balancer. All you need to do is start the appropriate Service Instances.

3) Yep, that's how it works.

4) You do not need any load balancer technology in place, it is done for you.

Of course, for Web Front Ends, you do need a load balancer.

Comment: Thanks. Should I start the services on both the app servers? Except user profile server.

Comment: @Trevor, i have a  doubt here, as far as i know, we should not activate the foundation web application  service in APP servers. Pls correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: For 2010 and 2013, you should start foundation Web on all servers.

Comment: We checked same for Central admin. Site is hosted on App1 and App2 but when we are clicking on SharePoint Central Admin link in Start menu then it is browsing the App1 CA only. If App1 is down then App2 should be browsable. is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, see http://www.harbar.net/articles/spca.aspx. You will need to place the Central Administration servers behind a network load balancer. As for your other question, yes you would start the services on both servers, e.g. Managed Metadata Service.